# Unable to import own mesh into gazebo

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi all,

I'm trying to use gazebo from ROS and my problem is the following: I have a mesh saved in .dae format that I want to load from a world file.

So, this is what I've done:

- I created a ros package and edited the package.xml file according to http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/6568/uri-paths-to-packages-in-the-sdf-model-file/
- In the package main folder, I created a folder named models
- In this folder I created a model named my_mesh with the actual mesh following these conventions http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=model_structure&cat=build_robot

Then, I wrote the following world file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<sdf version="1.4">
  <world name="default">
    <include>
      <uri>model://sun</uri>
    </include>
    <include>
      <uri>model://ground_plane</uri>
    </include>   
    <model name="my_mesh">
      <pose>0 0 0  0 0 0</pose>
      <static>true</static>
      <link name="body">
        <visual name="visual">
          <geometry>
            <mesh><uri>model://my_mesh</uri></mesh>
          </geometry>
        </visual>
      </link>
    </model>
  </world>
</sdf>
```

and the corresponding launch file:

```
<launch>

  <!-- these are the arguments you can pass this launch file, for example paused:=true -->
  <arg name="paused" default="false"/>
  <arg name="use_sim_time" default="true"/>
  <arg name="extra_gazebo_args" default=""/>
  <arg name="gui" default="true"/>
  <arg name="headless" default="false"/>
  <arg name="debug" default="false"/>
  <arg name="physics" default="ode"/>
  <arg name="verbose" default="false"/>
  <arg name="world_name" default="$(find mapping_environments)/worlds/my_mesh.world"/> 

  <!-- set use_sim_time flag -->
  <group if="$(arg use_sim_time)">
    <param name="/use_sim_time" value="true" />
  </group>

  <!-- set command arguments -->
  <arg unless="$(arg paused)" name="command_arg1" value=""/>
  <arg     if="$(arg paused)" name="command_arg1" value="-u"/>
  <arg unless="$(arg headless)" name="command_arg2" value=""/>
  <arg     if="$(arg headless)" name="command_arg2" value="-r"/>
  <arg unless="$(arg verbose)" name="command_arg3" value=""/>
  <arg     if="$(arg verbose)" name="command_arg3" value="--verbose"/>
  <arg unless="$(arg debug)" name="script_type" value="gzserver"/>
  <arg     if="$(arg debug)" name="script_type" value="debug"/>

  <!-- start gazebo server-->
  <node name="gazebo" pkg="gazebo_ros" type="$(arg script_type)" respawn="false" output="screen"
    args="$(arg command_arg1) $(arg command_arg2) $(arg command_arg3) -e $(arg physics) $(arg extra_gazebo_args) $(arg world_name)" />

  <!-- start gazebo client -->
  <group if="$(arg gui)">
    <node name="gazebo_gui" pkg="gazebo_ros" type="gzclient" respawn="false" output="screen"/>
  </group>

</launch>
```

but when I roslaunch the file, gazebo starts with an empty world.
Is there someone that can, please, explain me how to solve this problem?

Thanks!

---

EDIT:

@hamzamerzic according to http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/env, the env tag is deprecated and, in fact, it has no effect. There, it is suggested to use env-loader. But, if I'm not wrong, this is meant to be used in distributed machines settings. Do you have any clue on how I can solve this problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/16897/unable-to-import-own-mesh-into-gazebo/) by [federico.nardi](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3295/federico.nardi/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 23 on 2017-08-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hamzamerzic](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3232/hamzamerzic/) on 2017-08-02**:
What I find useful is setting the GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH env variable to point to the location of your custom models. You can add within your launch file the following command:
.

**Comment by [federico.nardi](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3295/federico.nardi/) on 2017-08-02**:
Yep, that works for sure. I'm going to follow your suggestion. Thanks

**Comment by [hamzamerzic](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3232/hamzamerzic/) on 2017-08-02**:
@federico.nardi This is strange, because I use that extensively and it works like a charm. You can find examples [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/261068/roslaunch-xml-env-tag/) and [here](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1684/when-importing-a-urdf-model-how-are-package-uris-parsed/). You can also set the environment variable in your .bashrc by adding export GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH="$(rospack find mapping_environments)/models", but I prefer to have everything in the launch file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The URI should be pointing to the mesh file, for example `model://my_model/meshes/mesh.dae`.

See an example [here](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo_models/src/73f89ecb1622f0bce7f9da3827958c40e62fb83f/bowl/model.sdf?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default).

I also recommend you use the `verbose` argument so you can see error messages which should help identify the issue.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2017-08-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1